# how to read an image from a function in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

how to read an image from a function in PIL ? in this scenerio i'm passing a image through paste_image function but it won't support PIL

```
def paste_image(image):
    for i in range(epoches):
        im2 = Image.open('/home/navaneeth/work/oneon/1.png')
        x, y = im2.size
        image.paste(im2, (0, 0, x, y))
        image.save("test_"+str(i)+".jpg", "JPEG")
```

and i'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 109, in <module>
paste_image(image)
File "main.py", line 98, in paste_image
image.paste(im2, (0, 0, x, y))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'paste'
```

Comment: I think paste is a method in "Image" not in "image" in your code. image is just a numpy array.

Comment: The image you are passing as a parameter is a numpy array not a PIL Image, so you can't call `paste()` because NumPy arrays don't have a paste method. Add a line before pasting that converts the NumPy array to a PIL Image `image = Image.fromarray(image)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell  thank you it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
im2 = Image.open("/home/navaneeth/work/oneon/1.png")
```

You can use this code to get the result you want.

Comment: i tried all the diffrent methods of quotes and so on but after i found the error.the image i'm  passing as a parameter is a numpy array not a PIL Image, so i was't call paste() because NumPy arrays don't have a paste method. later added a line before pasting that converts the NumPy array to a PIL Image image = Image.fromarray(image) then it works